# Unable to scrape class information with Find_All

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract class information form below website https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis. My code works fine for all pages except https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?page=2092.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?page=2092'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
apis = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':['odd views-row-first', 'odd','even','even views-row-last']})
print(apis)
```

On 2092 page I get info about only 1 class as below

```
[<tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-pw-version-title"> <a href="/api/inkling">Inkling API</a><br/></td><td class="views-field views-field-search-api-excerpt views-field-field-api-description hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm col-md-8"> Our REST API allows you to replicate much of the functionality in our hosted marketplace solution to build custom widgets and stock tickers for your Intranet, create custom reports, add trading...</td><td class="views-field views-field-field-article-primary-category"> <a href="/category/financial">Financial</a></td><td class="views-field views-field-pw-version-links"> <a href="/api/inkling-rest-api">REST v0.0</a></td></tr>]
```

For any other page (like https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?page=2091), I get info about all the classes. The HTML structure seems similar in all pages.

Comment: it's working fine for me , maybe try to sleep a few seconds between each request

Comment: @AhmedSoliman, can you please paste the print output you got?. I am a newbie here, can you also help with the sleep code you are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

This website is constantly adding new APIs to it's database So there is three scenarios here that might have caused this :

1. The selectors you are using is not accurate.
2. The website has
   some kinda security measure for you sending too many requests.
3. at
   the time of your scrape this page truly had one item on it .

scenario no 3 is most likely to believe .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep

for page in range(1,2094): #starting with 1 then the last page will be 2093
  url = f'https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?page={page}'
  response = requests.get(url)
  data = response.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
  apis = soup.select('table[class="views-table cols-4 table"] tbody tr') # better selector
  print(apis) #page 2093 currently has 6 items on it .
  sleep(5) #This will sleep for 5 secs
```

Comment: what do you mean by scenario no 3? Page (https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?page=2092) visually shows 6 APIs but code extracts only 1 API. I am trying above page only, not sure what is wrong. Even with your selector, I  am getting 1 API

Comment: @Learner I mean that your code could have been working fine but at the time of scraping this page it did only has one item and it's not an issue like you think it is .